# After installing firebase-tools on node 19 i get error about 'p-limit' module not being found

Tags: firebase

I'm on node 19,I have installed `npm install -g firebase-tools` then if I run the `firebase` command I get this error everytime:

```
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1093
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'p-limit'
Require stack:
- /usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/database/import.js
- /usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/commands/database-import.js
- /usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/commands/index.js
- /usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/index.js
- /usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/bin/firebase.js
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1090:15)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:934:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1157:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/helpers:119:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/database/import.js:8:19)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1275:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1329:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1133:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:972:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1157:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/helpers:119:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/commands/database-import.js:8:18)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1275:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1329:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1133:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:972:12) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/database/import.js',
    '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/commands/database-import.js',
    '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/commands/index.js',
    '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/index.js',
    '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/bin/firebase.js'
  ]
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like error in newest firebase-tools package. Just install some previous version:

```
npm install -g firebase-tools@9.17.0
```